# extraction of source code using the View source pages of Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was trying to extract the website source. I have tried some code that gives me the source code of the current website tab. Here it is:

```
 var req = new XMLHttpRequest();  
      req.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
req.open('GET', tab.url,false);   
req.send();  
if(req.status == 200)  
   alert(req.responseText);
```

But there is only one issue. I could see the code in the browser `View Source section` in Chrome But could not able to extract it. I guess this is a dynamic content.
So what I was thinking to achieve is to load the page as view source and then extract it using some chrome extension. But I am not getting the way out how I can get it. I know one thing that I can get the source code of the web page if I scrape the View Source page from the chrome browser.

Kindly suggest me what can be best possibly done to achieve it.

Comment: Why not just save the page to disk ["Save page as", (Ctrl-S)] and then look at the files that are saved? Doing so should give you the HTML, CSS and JavaScript files, as downloaded.

Comment: If not, what do you mean by "extract"? And, which content "source code" are you wanting to "extract" (the HTML, CSS, or JavaScript)? From the fact that you are using `XMLHttpRequest()` to fetch it, it appears you want the original code that's transmitted from the server, not the current contents of the DOM.